# How to switch between 3 different levels of a game using DOM and JavaScript? E.g. Easy, Medium and Hard

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying making a simple game using DOM and JavaScript, and within this game I've 3 different levels: easy, medium and hard. By default when the page loads the easy level is used! But I want to be able to switch between the 3 different levels using javascript!

It is possible to do this using javascript cookie session, so a particular function is being used/activated when a button is clicked, then that function is used until the user clicks on another button, say for example the medium level.

For example:

```
function easylevel() {
}

function mediumlevel() {
}

function hardlevel() {
}
```

So any of the above functions is activated and stored into a cookie session by clicking a button, for example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="easylevel()" value="Easy Level" />
<input type="button" onclick="mediumlevel()" value="Medium Level" />
<input type="button" onclick="hardlevel()" value="Hard Level" />
```

I've already tried this, but it doesn't works, can somebody please explain me where I'm going wrong! I'm 200% sure that I'm wrong because I don't know much about JS, so need help and advice for sure!

Comment: Please clarify what you want to know. How to set a cookie from JavaScript? How to respond to a button clicked with a function? How to replace HTML elements on page from within a function?

Comment: Because when I click on any of the buttons, the associated function only works for 1 sec and disappears, so I want somehow to activate only one of those functions at the time and once one of them is active the other two should be inactive... thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand what you wanted, but you could use setCookie() and getCookie() in JS?

Comment: Or if is possible to use 3 DIVs and each of them with 3 different IDs, so when I click on any of the button the associated DIV that contains a particular JavaScrpt code would be activated and the other two DIVs are still inactive! In other word the three DIVs are inactivate and stored into a cookie session, so even if refreshed the page the requested DIV is still active... would this work!

Comment: Here in this example http://jsfiddle.net/farzad/ERHRj/ as you can see, all of the 3 DIVs are active and shown, but I only want one of them to be active at them time and that depends on what button is clicked!

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is that a function is called repeatedly, then you could use `setInterval`

```
<script>
var intervalInMilliseconds = 1000; // change this to watever value you like
var activeInterval = undefined;
function startEasyLevel() {
    if (activeInterval) {
         clearInterval(activeInterval);
    }
    activeInterval = setInterval(easylevel, intervalInMilliseconds);
}
function startMediumLevel() {
    if (activeInterval) {
         clearInterval(activeInterval);
    }
    activeInterval = setInterval(mediumlevel, intervalInMilliseconds);
}
function startHardLevel() {
    if (activeInterval) {
         clearInterval(activeInterval);
    }
    activeInterval = setInterval(hardlevel, intervalInMilliseconds);
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="startEasyLevel()" value="Easy Level" />
<input type="button" onclick="startMediumLevel()" value="Medium Level" />
<input type="button" onclick="startHardLevel()" value="Hard Level" />
```

Add to this your current level functions and it should call the function every second. As soon as you click one of your buttons it will stop calling the current level function and continue to call the function associated with the clicked button.

If you want some level be loaded by default you can use the onload event of the window element:

```
window.onload = startEasyLevel;
```

Comment: Thanks! So even if the user refreshes the page the selected function is still active! Right?

Comment: By the way can I set the easy level to be loaded by default, so when the user visits the page for the first time, then the easy level is already loaded by default... Thanks :)

Comment: No, if you want to keep the function called after a refresh you will need to utilize cookies or some other session mechanism. See the [cookie documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) for details on how to store something in a cookie.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it! :)

Comment: Actually [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) is propably better suited for your case, since you do not require the information transferred to the server anyway.

Comment: Just a small update: I screwed up with ``document.onload``. It actually is ``window.onload``.

Comment: Thanks, that looks easier to me, really appreciate your help! :)